# how to use "MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS" injection token in angular material

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, autocomplete, angular-material, provider

how can i use the "MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS" injection token to configure globally whether the first element of the panel is highlighted for the autocomplete component in angular material
[https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api#MatAutocomplete][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to that docs it has only one this option - so just provide it your module where you need this option and that all.

```
providers: [
  {provide: MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {autoActiveFirstOption: true}}
]
```

Comment: first why use the proprety "useValue" ? and secondely when i add this to the module, "MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS" is unknown

Comment: Because you providing a value, obviously. There is chapter in documentation called 'Fundamentals' for a reason - https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#non-class-dependencies.

Comment: > "MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS" is unknown
So maybe need to import it?

Comment: Hi @itspers, i added th providers proprety like you suggested `providers: [
  {provide: MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {autoActiveFirstOption: true}}
]` then i declared à proprety `prop:boolean|undifined;` then i injected the token in the costructor like this `constructor(@Inject(MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS) dauk:MatAutocompleteDefaultOptions){  this.prop.dauk.autoActiveFirstOption
 }` and i binded the autoActiveFirstOption proprety to the prop proprety this way `[autoActiveFirstOption]="prop"` is it good ? if so what is the point of using the injectiontoken ?